# Adding Github Pages URL to Github repository's About section

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a Github repository with an associated Github page (say, github.com/user/mypage), and I would like to include the URL to the Github page (say, user.github.io/mypage) in the About section of the repository. When I go to "Edit repository details", the Github page already shows up in the "Website" field and cannot be changed (which is fine) but it is not displayed in the About section. I've tried this with multiple repositories with associated Github pages, and all show the same behavior. Am I overlooking something blatantly obvious, or is it just not possible to include the URL here?

Comment: I think that is placeholder text, not really an entry. Are you sure it cannot be changed? Do you own the repository? What exact input did you try that did not work?

Comment: Ok, turns out I was indeed overlooking something blatantly obvious, thanks! I had tried to remove the text first using the delete button, but I didn't try to just type in the URL, which works perfectly

Comment: Great, good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried for a week to link my `GitHub Page` to my `GitHub` repository.  I just figured out how to do it and then found this post.  I thought I would go ahead and post my answer.  Doing so might be helpful by making this question more visible in future internet search results.

Click on the gear icon in the upper-right of your `GitHub` repository to the right of the word "About" (shown in the red circle below):

[image]

Paste the `URL` of your `GitHub Page` into the `Website` bar in the window that pops up. This `Website` bar will already contain text that is grayed-out and might match the `URL` of your actual `GitHub Page`.  That grayed-out text is inactive.  Go ahead and paste in the `URL` of your `GitHub Page` anyway.  Then click `Save changes`.  You are done. Your `GitHub Page` should now be linked to your `GitHub` repository.

[image]